# Active Reports - How can I go to a specifc page in the Viewer?

Tags: c#, report, activereports, componentone

I'm using Active Reports 6 and display the report in our application in the Viewer control (not printed).  I need a way to determine the current page the user is showing, and I also need a way to restore the Viewer to a specific page.  I need this because when data is added to the report, the Viewer automatically resets to page 1.  I've searched high and low and cannot find a way to do either.  Can this be done in Active Reports and if so can anyone tell me how to do it?  Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You may make use of the '[CurrentPage](http://helpcentral.componentone.com/NetHelp/ActiveReports6/topic3094.html)' property of the ReportViewer that gets or sets the number of the current document page displayed in the viewer.

Regards,
Mohita